# Image not upload to php server ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, image-uploading, nsurlsession

Image not upload to php server ios 10 It gives error as

You did not select a file to upload.

This is the code

```
- (IBAction)changeProfilePic:(id)sender {

[[sharedClass sharedInstance]showprogressfor:@"Please wait"];


NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/as/web_services/change_user_image?user_id=%@",self.useridString];

UIImage *image= profile_Image;

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
request.timeoutInterval = 10.0f;
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *boundary = @"011000010111000001101001";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary, nil];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"projectId\"\r\n\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *stringData = [@"Content-Disposition: form-data;\
                      name=\"project\";\
                      fileName=\"photo.jpeg\"\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[body appendData:stringData];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

//    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

```
NSDictionary *statusDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
statusDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];

NSString *message = [statusDict valueForKey:@"msg"];

[SVProgressHUD dismiss];

NSLog(@" mesaage is %@", message);
```

}

Comment: change http to https in your link

Comment: My back end team give service witth http only how can i changed that.

Comment: Have you checked your url? There is a space at the start and you should check if the user id (if it's a string) doesn't have any special chars.

Comment: @ Luca D'Alberti  i removed that space also and my user id doesn't contains any special characters too. it gives message <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domine.com/as/web_services/change_user_image?user_id=%@",self.useridString];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 0.5);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0f;
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

        NSString *boundary = @"011000010111000001101001";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary, nil];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];



        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"projectId\"\r\n\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSData *stringData = [@"Content-Disposition: form-data;\
                              name=\"project\";\
                              fileName=\"photo.jpeg\"\r\n"
                              dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [body appendData:stringData];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding
```

Comment: NSURLConnection is deprecated in ios 10

Comment: <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p> it gives message in my debug.

Comment: **theImage** is my file name in  -  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 0.5);

Comment: you can use your profile image

Comment: i changed it even i get that error.

Comment: Could you please share screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131775/discussion-between-neha-mishra-and-lokesh).

Comment: check your project architecture according to your web service like name=\"project\";\  ,projectId.

Comment: Can you please explain clearly?

Comment: Check these things your code -
 1- NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 2- UIImageJPEGRepresentation
 Tell me what is the error you getting now

Comment: it print message as this "You did not select a file to upload".

Answer (score 1):

Remove space form the url

[image]

#### Copy below code to resolve your issue

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domine.com/as/web_services/change_user_image?user_id=%@",self.useridString];
```

Comment: i removed that space but also its not working. It gives my http request like this <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000234480> { URL: http://domine.com/as/web_services/change_user_image?user_id=2989557000 } { status code: 200, headers {

Comment: The status code  200 shows that request is successful

Comment: Can you explain clearly I didnt get you, Status Code 200 but my image is not uploaded.

Comment: @lokesh that's probably a backend error. On iOS side (in general any client side), if you receive status code 200, means you did your stuff right and the server also is supposed to have done its things right